# Репозиторий внутри репозитория

Tags: git

Подскажите, что будет, если папку с git-репозиторием добавить в другой git-репозиторий?

```
структура папок:
Level1/
    .git
    Level2/
        .git
        Level3
```

Comment: Что будет не знаю, но предположу, что подобное стоит делать через submodule

Comment: будет каталог с репозиторием в рабочей копии репозитория. а вы, видимо, ожидали чего-то особенного.

Answer (score 1):

смотря что подразумевается под словом «добавить».

если подразумевается скопировать/создать файлы/каталоги, то команда `git status`, выполненная в самом «верхнем» каталоге, покажет *untracked* файл `Level1/Level2/Level3` (если я правильно понял, что `Level3` — это файл, а не каталог). все остальные файлы/каталоги не будут (по умолчанию) показаны как *untracked* потому, что они (с точки зрения программы *git*) либо «пусты», либо их имена начинаются с точки.

если же под словом «добавить» подразумевается `git add Level1/.git`, то вы сразу же получите ошибку:

> error: Invalid path 'Level1/.git/HEAD'
>   error: unable to add Level1/.git/HEAD to index
>   fatal: adding files failed

такое защитное средство придумали разработчики: выдавать ошибку при попытке добавить в репозиторий файл с именем `HEAD`, расположенный в каталоге с именем `.git`.

---

кстати, то же самое относится и к файлам `.git/config`, `.git/description`, `.git/hooks/*` и `.git/info/*`.

---

так что, если вам действительно нужно добавить один репозиторий в другой, лучше воспользоваться «готовым» механизмом [`submodule`](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8).